# Hide DataGrid when no record exist

Tags: wpf, xaml

Currenly I have requirement to Hide my data grid control when there is no records are populated in it.

I tried setting it like below but it didn't work.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True" Visibility="{Binding Employees.Count>0, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"></DataGrid>
```

Please suggest me a solution for this

Answer (score 3):

You can create either custom converter but in my opinion, in this case, it's easier to simply use `Style.Trigger` which will set `Visiblility` to Collapsed when `Employees.Count` is 0, like so:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Employees.Count}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Style>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use a converter that converts an integer into visibility. In your case 0 to hidden/collapsed and everything above 0 to visible.

Using expressions in binding paths is not possible, because WPF internally uses reflection to find the value of the property.

In your case the converter would look like this:

```
public class CountToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type TargetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int count = value as int;
        if(count != null && count > 0) return Visibility.Visible;
        else return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You have to implement `IValueConverter`. `Convert` is used to convert from the binding to the actual value. `ConvertBack` would be used to convert in the opposite direction.

To use it you have to reference your assembly and add it as static resource, like what you did with BooleanToVisibilityConverter.

Comment: Are you talking about BooleanToVisibilityConverter ? If yes i have done that

Comment: you can create your own converter. I'll post an example

Answer (score 0):

I modified @dkozl answer to remove the dependency on the `ItemSource` name. Now we can add to all `DataGrid` regardless of the `ItemSource` definition.

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Items.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Style>
</DataGrid>
```

If your having problems with this solution remove the `Visibility` attribute from the `DataGrid` itself. Allow the trigger to determine visibility.